# CUDA functions cannot be compiled

Tags: cudalink

[image]

[image]

i5-3210M, GT 630M;
Windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio 2013;
CUDA 6.5 has been installed.

One of the clues I found is that GT 630M didn't appear in the list of graphics cards supported by CUDALink which shows that GT 640M is required. I wonder if it is the exact cause.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Some Code to copy would be nice.

Comment: GT 630M is supported according to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus and http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-630m.

Comment: You could try a re-installation. First uninstall with `CUDAResourcesUninstall[]`, than download the proper paclet from http://www.wolfram.com/CUDA/CUDAResources.html and install it (using your file direction) with `CUDAResourcesInstall["D:\\Downloads\\CUDAResources-Win64-10.0.0.1.paclet"]`. **Do not** use `CUDAResourcesInstall[]` or `CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]` as these maybe install an older version.